# Is there a way to bypass Chrome startup pages when desired?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, boot

In Chrome (Windows 7) I have multiple Startup pages/tabs that launch when Chrome starts. Normally this is fine, but other times I do not want the multiple startup pages launching. Is there a way to bypass the startup pages when starting up Chrome? Maybe there is a key I can hold down when starting Chrome that will do this?

Comment: Which operation system do you use ?

Comment: Doesn't holding "shift" while Chrome is launching keep it barebones? (I don't have a copy of Chrome here to test with.)

Comment: @AlEverett I just tried the shift key idea but it did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows:

Create a link to "chrome.exe about:blank", e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" about:blank
```

Then when you open the link, chrome will launch with a single clean tab.

EDIT: If chrome is already opened, a new blank tab will be appended to the current opened chrome.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito
```

Will open a new clean window in [stealth mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464), regardless to whether a chrome is already opened or not.

Comment: Something like `chrome.exe --incognito` might also help (not tested, don't have Chrome).

Comment: True, I tested it and it does work, its [stealth mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464) though.

Comment: Yes of course, but if that's acceptable I guess it would work as an alternate solution to yours. You can add it to your answer if you wish.

Comment: Excellent thanks! mmmm... is there a parameter to make the Chrome new tab page appear rather than blank page? i.e. the tab displaying any installed Chrome apps

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 2 cents that this problem occurred for me as well and the resolution above worked well. I went to the file explorer and typed in the shortcut above that ends in —incognito but pls note that I had to remove the “ for it to work. As soon as I did it opened the incognito window of chrome (and nothing else) and I was then able to clear out all the browsing data/history (and change settings for what happens on startup) thanks!

Comment: Please don't post "thank you" comments as answers.